# Непересекающиеся фигуры

Tags: алгоритм, математика

Задача: рисовать в некой области случайные непересекающиеся квадраты.

Очевидное решение - сгенерировать координаты очередного квадрата и проверить их на пересечение с каждым уже существующим квадратом. Соответственно, когда квадратов становится много, это решение дает понять, что оно не является оптимальным. :)

Кто-нибудь может предложить что-то более интересное?

Comment: Возникает несколько вопросов: какая форма области? Квадраты разного размера? Квадраты могут быть повернутыми?

Comment: прямоугольная, да, да

Comment: Квадрат в квадрате быть может?

Comment: нет конечно!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поддерживать в актуальном состоянии набор пустых выпуклых областей. После добавления очередного квадрата в какую-то пустую область, заменить эту область подходящими кусками меньшего размера.

Области можно организовать в R-дерево, чтобы быстро искать свободное место.

Например, как рисуем очередной квадрат: выбираем случайную точку. Находим по дереву ближайшую область S. Если точка не в S, придумываем какой-нибудь трюк, чтобы получить точку в S (ну нарисуем диаметр области, проведенный через точку и циклически так отразим её на другой конец области по этому диаметру :)). Получив точку, назовём её центром квадрата (или пусть будет верхним левым углом) и достроим квадрат на основе случайных угла поворота и длины стороны (с ограничением, чтоб не вылезти за пределы области).

Из-за последнего ограничения квадрат не совсем случайный. Но можно искать недостающее пространство опять же по дереву и заимствовать площадь.

А вообще с R-деревом ваш метод не так уж и плох. Надо проиндексировать квадраты и переодически переиндексировать, т. к. при динамическом добавлении квадратов R-дерево деградировать начнёт. При попадании точки в квадрат, отчеканить её за границы квадрата. Затем найти ограничение - максимальный свободный круг с центром в найденной случайной точке, случайно выбрать длину диагонали (половина которой ограничена радиусом окружности) и угол поворота и построить квадрат.

Comment: А вообще должно быть простое решение. :) Придумаю - допишу

Answer (score 1):

При рендеринге сцен с помощью трассировки лучей используют структуру, называемую octtree - т.е. делят пространство на 8 кубов, потом каждый куб на 8 кубов и т.д. Каждый из кубов содержит список объектов, которые в нем находятся (условно). Возможно, Вам поможет аналогичное разбиение на плоскости - 4 квадрата, каждый - еще на 4 и так далее... т.о. есть возможность быстро проверить есть ли в квадрате с выбранной точкой какие-либо сгенерированные объекты и проверить пересечения с ними по одному (т.е. аналогично вашему первому решению, только количество проверяемых объектов будет мало)

Answer (score 0):

использовать растр, для складирования форм - а значит возможности проверки... заполнять начиная с больших форм к маленьким...

Comment: используй растр... для накопления результата и как следствие - возможности быстрой проверки...

Comment: А что это значит? Можно поподробнее?

Answer (score 0):

*Если при описании границы фигуры A есть хоть одна точка, которая лежит на одной прямой между точками границы фигуры B, для которых Направление описание соответственно противоположно, то фигуры пересекаются.*